# how to write a remote file using the tomcat and java

Tags: java, android, apache, tomcat

**how to write a remote file using the tomcat and java. I use this java code :**

```
HttpURLConnection connexion = null;    
try {
URL("http://localhost:8080/GeneralSemanticWebService/Models/pervasiveSystemDescription1.txt");
System.out.println("Connexion a l'url ...");
connexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connexion.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
connexion.setDoOutput(true);
connexion.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", (""+ texte.length()));
connexion.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connexion.getOutputStream());
if (connexion.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
System.out.println(connexion.getResponseMessage());
} else {
System.out.println("Ecriture ...");
out.write("okkkk");
out.close();}   
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
connexion.disconnect();
}
System.exit(0);
```

**In the output I have this result :**

```
INFOS: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
janv. 06, 2015 6:27:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
janv. 06, 2015 6:27:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFOS: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
janv. 06, 2015 6:27:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFOS: Server startup in 54713 ms
Connexion a l'url ...
Ecriture ...
janv. 06, 2015 6:27:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFOS: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

**and the server is stopped.
Please respond me**

Answer (score 1):

In this code path, you are closing `out`, which is a PrintWriter wrapper around connextion's OutputStream, then calling `connextion.disconnect()`.  I suspect that the `.disconnect()` method attempts to close the stream again, causing an exception or some error you're not capturing.  I suggest to remove the `out.close()` and try again.

Answer (score -1):

I used this code :

```
HttpURLConnection connexion = null;    

try {

URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/GeneralSemanticWebService/Models/pervasiveSystemDescription1.txt");

System.out.println("Connexion a l'url ...");

        connexion = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();



connexion.setAllowUserInteraction(true);
                connexion.setDoOutput(true);
                connexion.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", (""+ texte.length()));
                connexion.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "RDF/XML-ABBREV");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(connexion.getOutputStream());
                if (connexion.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                System.out.println(connexion.getResponseMessage());
                } else {
                System.out.println("Ecriture ...");
                out.write("okkkk");
                }   
                } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

But the file pervasiveSystemDescription1.txt is not modified, and the String ("okkkk") is not written in this file.

Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: You can't just write data to a file on the remote server like that, you need some sort of remote endpoint that's listening for stuff to write, be it over http POST or sockets or something, you can't simply write text to a file on a url and expect the webserver to write it though.